# How to set permissions on the default audio device so that it can be changed programmatically?

Tags: windows, audio, device

Right now I'm trying to set the default audio device on Windows 7 programmatically, and the main issue I'm running into right now is permissions.  I've gone into regedit.exe and tried to set these permissions, but that's turning out to be something of an issue.  Any advice?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN [Working with Device Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370821%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Applications cannot change the roles that are assigned to audio
>   endpoint devices. The operating system allows only the user to assign
>   device roles.